# ArcMap's base map with imagery collection date

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, imagery, arcgis-online-basemaps

How can I determine the collection date for ArcMap's base map with imagery? I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Identify tool. click on the map, the SRC_DATE (source date) field should have your information.